# How can I use friendly/rewritten urls in php?

Tags: php

I have problem to encrypt the url.

example

existing url=  www.domainname/search.php?key=books&type=title&Submit=search

i want to encrypt this url.

encrypt url=  www.domainname/keword-keyword-keyword.html

in this form...

can any one solve my problem..
i will be greatfull to him or her

Comment: That's usually called URL rewriting, rather than encrypting.

Comment: No one can understands you. You need many more words and real examples of what you want to achieve. Also since you have spammed the same question three times, maybe no one will help you anyway?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using PHP, you may well be on an Apache server - in which case you can use Apache's mod_rewrite to provide restful URIs to your visitors.

Here is a short example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^Search/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ search.php?key=$1&type=$2&term=$3 [L,NC]
```

This would translate

```
http://www.domainname/Search/books/title/Mission%20Impossible/
```

Into

```
http://www.domainname/search.php?key=books&type=title&term=Mission%20Impossible
```

The [L] means no further rules would be evaluated
The [NC] makes this case-insensitive (so "Search" and "search" would both work)

Answer (score 2):

This is called **Friendly URL**: http://www.google.com/search?q=friendly+URL

- http://www.petefreitag.com/item/503.cfm
- http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/search-engine-friendly-urls
- http://www.seoconsultants.com/articles/1000/urls.asp

Comment: @Sushant - No.. they're articles about how you can do that... It's just too long to explain here. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to use a PHP file as common part of the path and parse the request URI yourself. E.g.

http://www.example.com/index.php/books/AliceInWonderland

In this case, index.php could parse the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].