# How to remove file extensions from urls?

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have a website where I want to remove file extensions when displayed in the URL, so for example I want to change '/home.php' to '/home'. How would I go about doing this using the .htaccess file, iv'e looked elsewhere but there seem to be different variations and I cant get any to work. Thanks

My hoster is 'ehosting'.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206649/how-can-i-use-friendly-rewritten-urls-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Use the following .htaccess rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: arr lol i tried it and it still dont work, its in the root directory and it sais 'apache security file' and everything tho lol so god knows why it doesn't work